# Too many redirects. Rirect path to subfolder using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, revolution-slider

I've ulploaded wordpress in subdirectory to intall. Path of it is
`public_html/revslider-standalone`

This is full path
http://greenlinerenovations.com/revslider-standalone

When I open this URL in browser, it says too many redirects. Below is my code for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^About+$ about.php
RewriteRule ^FAQ+$ faq.php
RewriteRule ^Contact+$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^Gallery+$ gallery.php
RewriteRule ^Areas-we-service+$ cities.php


RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ servicesparse.php?name=$1
```

What rule should be added or corrected to install Wordpress on that path ?
Redirects in htaccess file is neccessory so can't remove it. Is there anyway to add new rule and it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^About$ about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^FAQ$ faq.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Contact$ contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Gallery$ gallery.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Areas-we-service$ cities.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ servicesparse.php?name=$1
```

With `RewriteCond` before the last rule `RewriteRule`

Comment: `RewriteCond` Works only for the next first `RewriteRule`